# proxypass https from one servet to another as https

Tags: apache-2.2, https, proxypass

I have serverA which act as a reverse proxy for serverB. What i wish to accomplish is to porxypass an https connection  from serverA to serverB. In other words:

```
---https-->(serverA)---proxypass-https--->(serverB)
```

ServerA runs apache2 and ServerB runs nginx.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `SSLProxyEngine On` will do the trick. What i actually did was set the vhost file on ServerA as per bellow:

```
<VirtualHost serverA:443>
  ServerName serverA.example.com
  SSLProxyEngine On
  ProxyPass / https://serverB.example.com
  ProxyPassReverse / https://seerverB.exampe.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. It's very straigtforward, just set up your backend server/vhost as you would a front facing server. You can use different certs on both servers or you can use the same certs on both, just make sure that the front server nameservice resolves the backend correctly.